# How to retrieve the published post in wordpress database?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm trying to build a custom script of mine and I need to retrieve data from a wordpress database. I have to get the posts content in the database, but when I surf through the wp_posts table in phpmyadmin I see that there are lots of rows with mostly the same content, saved drafts, auto saved posts and so on.

So what I want is a SQL command that will give me the content of the published post and ignore all the drafts and saved posts. It's basically the command that wordpress uses when displaying a post (it displays the final, published one).

Hopefully I was clear enough.

Comment: Anything you have tried so far? :) Can you show us your tables schema and expected sample output?

Comment: Apparently anything but googling ;) http://www.elegantwebdesigns.net/2010/06/show-only-wp-recent-published-posts/

Comment: I tried nothing. At first I thought there should be some constraints about the posts date, but I still haven't found the answer.

Comment: @abyssal: SO isn't here to do your research for you. Have a look at the link I posted in my comment.

Comment: I found the post_status row, got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from wp_posts
where post_status = 'publish'
and post_type = 'post'
```

Comment: figured it, thanks, I didn't saw the post_status row, my bad.